# callback to User.find() just hangs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to write a migration script using Mongoose (no express here). But the callback just hangs. Script should exit, I do not want to forcibly exit. Is there anyway I can do this?

```
User.find().exec(function(err, users){
    console.log(users);

    return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to close the db connection. Otherwise the script just hangs:

```
User.find().exec(function(err, users){
    console.log(users);

    mongoose.connection.close()
});
```